# Full file path on Bash prompt

Tags: bash, ps1

Currently my bash prompt looks like this

```
[user_name@server]$
```

when I `cd` into a path `/dir1/dir2/dir3`

it changes to

```
[user_name@server dir3]$
```

I want it to show the full path as

```
[user_name@server dir1/dir2/dir3]$
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-prompt.html 
you want to change `\W` to `\w` in your PS1 variable

Comment: Check out this https://github.com/vaniacer/info-bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `PS1="[\u@\h: \w/]\$"` in your bash setup scripts (`~/.bashrc` for me) then you will get (eg) `[alan@alan-Z87MX-D3H: ~/]$`