# The hostname and current work path is not displayed in Linux terminal

Tags: linux

I have activated something on my Linux machine which caused the screen to only display `(base)` instead of `(base) [user@host path]$`. When I deactivate it, the screen remains blank which is not normal. I want to restore the normal screen. I have searched for solutions but haven't found anything helpful. I am not sure what this issue is related to so I am not able to search for relevant keywords. How can I fix this?

Current screen:

```
(base) python foo.py
```

Desired screen:

```
(base) [user@host path]$ python foo.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to look for the place where your prompt shell variable is overloaded in the shell script that you sourced. The variable name is usually $PS1.
You can see its definition using :

```bash
echo $PS1
```

And you can modify it using :

```bash
export PS1="[\u@\h: \w/]\$"  # for example
```

Similar question: [Full file path on Bash prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71910898/full-file-path-on-bash-prompt) .